# Responsive Datatable Th Data Property Get

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, datatables

I have datatable as below.

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th data-colid="id">ID</th>
  <th data-colid="name">Name</th>
  <th data-colid="email">Email</th>
  <th data-colid="address">Address</th>
  <th data-colid="action">Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

I used `responsive:true` so in mobile, the last two columns will be put into dropdown.

Here is dropdown area HTML part generated by datatable as default.

```html
<ul class="dtr-details">
 <li data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="3">
   <span class="dtr-title">Address</span> 
   <span class="dtr-data">Address data Here</span>
 </li>
 <li data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="4">
   <span class="dtr-title">Action</span> 
   <span class="dtr-data">Action Data Here</span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to get `data-colid` property when I click responsive dropdown `<li>`area.

`data-dt-column` this property didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a jQuery delegated event listener to access the column index from properties such as this (auto-generated by DataTables):

```
data-dt-column="4"
```

Using that, you can then use the DataTables API to access the table heading node for that index - and finally access the ``data-colid` attribute from the heading:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#example').DataTable( {
    responsive: true
  } );

$( "#example" ).on( "click", "tbody tr td ul li", function() {
  var colIdx =  $( this ).attr("data-dt-column");
  var headingNode = $('#example').DataTable().column( colIdx ).header();
  //console.log( $(headingNode).html() ); // the title text
  console.log( $(headingNode).attr("data-colid") ); // the property in the question
});

} );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable nowrap cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-colid="name">Name</th>
                <th data-colid="department">Department</th>
                <th data-colid="office">Office</th>
                <th data-colid="age">Age</th>
                <th data-colid="start_date">Start Date</th>
                <th data-colid="salary">Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Note that the event listener needs to be attached to an element which is guaranteed to exist in the DOM when the page is created - so I used the table ID as the selector:

```
$( "#example" )
```

Then I used the `"tbody tr td ul li"` selector to locate the specifically generated `<li>` elements.

Comment: Hi @andrewjames Your solution worked perfectly.

One question though. 

```var table = ```  ```table.column( colIdx ).header()``` Let's say we don't know ```table``` object because I want to use this feature for all datatables (generalized). I can get only table Id (Not table instance). Could you please let me know how to do it?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment, but... If you know the table ID, then you can replace the `table` variable with `$( "#the_table_id_goes_here").DataTable()`. So, in my example it would be: `$('#example').DataTable().column( colIdx ).header()` See the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/).

Comment: This didn't work. ```$('#example').DataTable().column( colIdx ).header()``` I think it's because datatable is alread initialized.

Comment: It works for me - I edited my answer's snippet as a demo. There must be something else going on. Can you clarify what you mean by "didn't work"? Any console errors, for example?

Comment: I would love to get ```table``` object which is already initialized using #id.

Comment: I don't really know what your comment means, sorry. What code are you using which generates that error? You can provide a Fiddle or edit your question.

Comment: Also, please check that you are typing your code the same way as I typed mine. For example, it's `DataTable()` not `Datatable()`.

Comment: Hey You are awesome. It worked! ```DataTable()``` Thank you so much!